# How can i set a specific and irregular tick on a Matlab axis?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

With Open-BCI, i got values (sampled at 255Hz) that i want to plot on matlab. However, i would like specific ticks on the x axis (i think it's the correct term) to match the acquisition protocol. It follows a 6-2-6-2 seconds pattern. What i mean is :

```
- T=0s => xtick="Image1"
- T=6s => xtick="Image2"
- T=8s => xtick="Image3"
- T=14s => xtick="Image4"
- T=16s => xtick="Image5"
etc...
```

I want to plot the whole signal, and then change the X axis ticks to show only those values.
However i struggle with matlab, so i have no idea how to do that. I'm not sure it's even possible.

Thank you, if you could help me

Comment: It is something similar to `set(gca,'xtick',[0,6,8,14,16])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your desired ticks in a matrix (e.g., "myticks" below).

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
figure
plot(x,x)
myticks = [1 3 3.5 4];
xticks(myticks)
```

yields this:
[image]